Google BigQuery. errorcode: Field name '"MovieTitle' is not supported by the current character map
I started doing a course where I use Google BigQuery to try out SQL with a spreadsheet about a movie theater. I want to upload a CSV file to BigQuery but i keep getting an error with the field name.
If someone has experienced this problem before and knows a fix, please let me know.
In the instructions it's as simple as downloading the CSV file, selecting auto-detect for schema and pressing create table. I can't however seem to be able to create the table because I keep getting an error like: Failed to create table: Field name 'Director (1)' is not supported by the current character map. Please change your field name or use character map V2 to let the system modify the field names.
i realised that () was not supported so i changed it to Director_1, which seemed to help the problem in that field but i can't get rid of the last error where I get the error code: Failed to create table: Field name 'Revenue;' is not supported by the current character map. Please change your field name or use character map V2 to let the system modify the field names.
note: Revenue is the final column and I dont have the semicolon written in my CSV file so i can't get rid of it.
the first line looks like this: Movie_Title,Release_Date,Wikipedia_URL,Genre,Director_1,Director_2,Cast_1,Cast_2,Cast_3,Cast_4,Cast_5,Budget,Revenue

Paste or supply a link to a sample of the CSV (eg. the first couple of lines).  I hear you say that "Revenue;" does not end in a semicolon in your file ... but the error seems to indicate that one was found.  Check that you are pointing to the file you think you are pointing to.

I "fixed" the problem by copying the entire thing into an an empty notepad file and then uploading it to BigQuerry in the same way. So i did not change anything but atleast now it worked :)

i had the same issue and at the end i found the problem.
When you create the table you must change in advanced options the Map of characters (dont really know in english, im using in my native language). Change it to V1. It will work!
